# Can I use webpack for creating a single js file for all my application code with its libraries?

Tags: webpack

I've created [this web app on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/deck-gl-point-nfx7o?file=/app.js) that prints some GeoJSON data on a map with Deck.gl. It has a `webpack.config.js` file and it's working fine... However, I'd like to know a way of compiling this application into a single js file, including the code that I've developed with its libraries included. I want to do that because with this js file I'd be able to embed this application inside a different app that uses only pure Javascript.

Basically, the `webpack.config.js` from the project is:

```
const CONFIG = {
  mode: "development",

  entry: {
    app: "./app.js"
  },

  output: {
    library: "App"
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: {
          presets: [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            "@babel/react",
            {
              plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = (env) =>
  env ? require("../../webpack.config.local")(CONFIG)(env) : CONFIG;
```

And its current `package.json` is:

```
{
  "name": "deck-gl-point",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start-local": "webpack-dev-server --env.local --progress --hot --open",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --progress --hot --open"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "@deck.gl/aggregation-layers": "8.3.3",
    "csvtojson": "2.0.10",
    "global": "4.3.2",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8",
    "deck.gl": "^8.6.0-alpha.0",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-map-gl": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "webpack": "^4.20.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "description": ""
}
```

I know `webpack` is made for bundling projects in single files. But I don't know how to start modifying these files for generating a single js file for my project... Is it possible to do? What do I have to modify in order to bundle this project into a single file?

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the purpose of Webpack. If your code is just JavaScript, your configuration is mostly right. But you also, have some HTML and CSS along with that JS code which I assume must also be shipped with your single file.

Adding CSS is easy. You need to use [`css-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-loader) and [`style-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/style-loader). Import the CSS code from JavaScript instead of referencing the file directly inside the `index.html`.

```
// app.js file
import './style.css';
```

For your HTML part, you have multiple options. Write the HTML code inside the JavaScript file using template literal and when the app loads, add this HTML to DOM using `innerHTML` or `DocumentFragment`. Alternately, you can use [`html-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-loader) to load HTML from separate file and then inject using `innerHTML`, etc. But since, you are already using `Vue` and `React`, you probably can move the initial HTML to respective libraries.

Once, everything is moved to JavaScript, we can use same configuration that you have provided with minor tweaks for the `entry` and `output` configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./app.js",

  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }
}
```

Since you don't have multiple entry points, I changed `entry` to use `string` instead of object format. You can then use it as a CDN link or equivalent:

```
<script src="https://example.com/path-to-bundle-library/bundle.js"></script>
```

This also assumes that the page where you are adding this JS code will have required DOM elements.

To go into more details, Webpack provides **two ways to bundle your code**. First is a application bundle and second is a library bundle which can then be used in other packages.

When using Webpack for application bundling, you do not get any exported object. You simply take the bundled JS file, add it to your HTML using `script` and then it executes immediately like IIFE. This is what we have done here.

In case of a library bundle, things are a bit more complex. With this way, whatever you export from `app.js` file would be available for consumption using global object `App` in your calling application. So, it is advisable to not have any direct side-effect (directly running the code as soon as file is added to the page). In your code, the top-most `for` loop, jQuery functions `$(#range)`, etc. are those side effects. Ideally, you should wrap all of this code inside some `main` or `initialize` function and export that.

When bundling using library, you get all the the exports available under the global object with a name you provide to the `library` field in the `output` configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./app.js",

  output: {
    library: "App"
  }
};
```

You can then use it as:

```
<script src="https://example.com/path-to-bundle-library/my-library.js"></script>
<script>
  // Run the code
  App.initialize();
</script>
```

Further as an optional step, you should consider few more things if you need to bundle the code as library:

1. The module format you want to use - ES Module, CommonJS, UMD, etc.
2. How to ship your library for others to consume - CDN, NPM registry, etc.

These decisions will change Webpack configuration slightly.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to make it work here yet. I managed to generate a bundled file by configuring the `webpack.conf.js` as you said and using the command `webpack -p`. But I'm not completely sure if using this command is what I'm supposed to do. I'm still encountering some problems with Vue even though I have declared the html and css loaders in it.  I see the error `import declarations may only appear at top level of a module`. I'm beginning to think it's a problem with my javascript code and not necessarily the `webpack.conf.js` file.

Comment: I've updated my changes on the [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/deck-gl-point-nfx7o?file=/app.js). The error `import declarations may only appear at top level of a module`  appears only when I use `npm install` on my local computer. On codesandbox it works.  The bundled file generated with `webpack -p` locally with this code still gives me errors with Vue.

Comment: After looking at the code, I see that you have configured the webpack loader properly, but you still need to add CSS and HTML as part of your dependency graph i.e. by importing these files directly inside the `app.js`.

Comment: This is the line that is causing the error that you see `<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>`. If you are trying to load the HTML file in the browser locally, you have to set the script to the bundled `script` i.e. `dist/app.bundle.js`. I was able to locally build your project and run it successfully.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still having trouble making it work. The CSS import we can do it with `import './style.css'`. However, it's not very clear to me how I'd call the HTML from `app.js`. Is it supposed to be something like `import './index.html'`?